# Accessibility of a friend function

Tags: c++, oop, friend

```
class C2;   //Forward Declaration

class C1
{
    int status;

    public:
    void set_status(int state);
    void get_status(C2 y);
};

class C2
{
    int status;

    public:
    void set_status(int state);
    friend void C1::get_status(C2 y);
};

//Function Definitions

void C1::set_status(int state)
{
    status = state;
}

void C2::set_status(int state)
{
    status = state;
}

void C1::get_status(C2 y)   //Member function of C1
{
    if (y.status | status)
    cout<<" PRINT " <<endl;
}
```

`y.status` in the second last line displays an error:

> C2::status is inaccessible

The code executes properly, but there is a red line (error) under `y.status`.

Why is this?

Comment: How does the code execute properly with the error "C2::status is inaccessible"?

Comment: How can you use C2 in the definition of class C1 ?

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I have no idea! Actually it should  be accessible.

Christophe - Its only being used as a parameter. That is why I had to use forward declaration.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds to me like the compiler (or part of a compiler) used by your IDE has a problem. I added enough to your code to get a complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class C2;   //Forward Declaration

class C1
{
    int status;

public:
    void set_status(int state);
    void get_status(C2 y);
};

class C2
{
    int status;

public:
    void set_status(int state);
    friend void C1::get_status(C2);
};

//Function Definitions

void C1::set_status(int state) {
    status = state;
}

void C2::set_status(int state) {
    status = state;
}

void C1::get_status(C2 y)   //Member function of C1
{
    if (y.status | status)
        cout << " PRINT " << endl;
}

int main() {

    C1 c;
    C2 d;
    d.set_status(1);

    c.get_status(d);
}
```

This compiled (without errors or warnings, at with default flags) with g++ 4.9 and VC++ 12 (aka VC++ 2013). Both produced: `PRINT` as output.

It's pretty common for an IDE to parse the source code separately from the actual compiler, and some of them are fairly limited compared to real compilers, so I guess it's not terribly surprising that they get confused about some things.

Comment: Hi, I wrote the same thing in main. I have not included the whole code in the question :)